# TestNG - Skip all classes in case of failures

Tags: testng

My tetsng suite as shown below - in case of any failures in the MyTest1 skips all other `@Test` methods in MyTest1 which is just great! However MyTest2 still executes. I would like to completely skip all the classes and go to next Test.

```
<test name="how to skip">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.test.MyTest1" />    <!-- if anything fails here, skip MyTest2 -->
        <class name="com.test.MyTest2" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no out of the box solution for this that TestNG gives you. You should be able to build this on your own by doing the following :

1. Build a listener which implements `IInvokedMethodListener` wherein from within its `beforeInvocation()` you start checking if the `ITestContext` object that is associated with the current `ITestResult` has any failures. If there are failures then you throw a `SkipException` from within the `beforeInvocation()`
2. Wire in this listener via the `<listeners>` tag or using the SPI model (Service loaders) or using the `@Listeners` annotation.

That should suffice